# XSLT preserve white space in list column name WITHIN variable

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2013

Thank you in advance if you answer this. We've looked EVERYWHERE and have hit a wall.

I'm working from a SharePoint 2013 calendar.  There's a list item called "Start Date".  In the XSLT, I'm attempting to reference this to create a variable, but the white space is causing an error.

Does anyone know how to preserve this white space WITHIN the attribute being referenced from a SharePoint list item so it can be used to create a variable ($date)?  I know there are many ways to preserve white space in XSLT (or remove it), but none of those methods seem to work in this instance.

Another caveat, we cannot rename the column (Start Time), since it's a global list content type/attribute that needs to retain the space for other applications.
Any assistance is appreciated!

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Start Time), 1033, 1)"/>
<xsl:variable name="day" select="format-number(substring-before(substring-after($date,'/'),'/'),'00.')"/>
```

We're using this calculation to extract the month and create a numerical representation (ie: Dec = 12) to create grouping options for a custom web part that outputs the calendar in a very custom way)

1. The SharePoint Calendar List Item:[image]
2. The XSLT Code: [image]
3. The desired output (grouping with month displaying in numerical format)[image]

Comment: `@` is used to denote an attribute, not a variable. Although spaces are not allowed in either attribute names or variable names. Can you show how this "Start Date" is actually defined? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your feedback, and apologies for my (shaky?) lingo.

I have an event I've created in a SharePoint 2013 calendar.  One of the fields is "Start Date" (I believe this is SP default column name).

What I'm trying to do is take that start date (date & time), and reformat the date so it is more user friendly. (1033 , 7).

Comment: I am also using it to extract the month (to create grouping options for a custom web part that outputs the calendar in a very custom way)

<xsl:variable name="date" select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Start Time), 1033, 1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="format-number(substring-before(substring-after($date,'/'),'/'),'00.')"/>

I hope that helps!

Comment: I'm attempting to create a variable ($day) using the attribute @Start  Date, which is a SharePoint default list item in the calendar.

I hope that makes better sense.

Comment: Is it possible for you to get hold of the XML that your XSLT is being applied to in SharePoint. I suspect "Start Date" isn't actually an attribute name, but the value of an attribute on the list item. For example `name="Start Date"`.

Comment: Thank you for your patience Tim.  I updated my original questions with a few support images.  The column "Start Time" (sorry for confusing you with Start Date) is a column content type that's associated with SharePoint calendars.  I'm simply trying to take the default list content type, grab it's data, and stuff it into a variable so I can transform it into a numerical month (Dec = 12) so I can group it.

I am able to get this to work when I create my OWN list content types, because I can remove the space that's breaking the XSLT.  However, since this is a global content type, I can't change.

Comment: @BirdieGolden I am afraid that's all irrelevant to the problem. We need to see the raw XML source that you are trying to transform. I am not familiar with SharePoint, but try to apply a stylesheet that contains **only** the *identity transform* template and post the resulting code here. If the source truly contains an attribute with a space in its name, this experiment will fail because your input is not XML - and you won't be able to use XSLT to process it.